# How to make files unique or check if they exist JAVA SERVER SIDE multi file upload

Tags: java, filenames

I am trying to ensure files are unique when being saved to a path. How can i check whether they exist, if so append a number to the filename at the beginning or end before the extension?

```
private static String UPLOADED_FOLDER = "C://temp//";

@RequestMapping(value = { "/fileUpload" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public String uploadFile( @RequestParam("number") String number, @RequestParam("files[]") MultipartFile[] files, MultipartHttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
{       

    for (MultipartFile file : files) {

    try {
        File directory = new File(UPLOADED_FOLDER + number);
        logger.info(directory.toString());
                if (! directory.exists()){
                    directory.mkdir();
                    logger.info("directory created");
                  }
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            logger.info(bytes.toString());
            Path path = Paths.get(UPLOADED_FOLDER + number + "//" + file.getOriginalFilename());
            logger.info(path.toString());
            Files.write(path, bytes);
            logger.info("You have successfully uploaded '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'");
            //return("File Uploaded");


    } catch (Exception e) {
        res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
        logger.error("Failed to upload file '" + file.getOriginalFilename() + "'", e);
        //return("File Not Uploaded");
    }
}
    return "redirect:/fileUpload";
}

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's quite easy:

```
    long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String sig = Long.toHexString(millis);
    System.out.println(sig);
```

Will produce something like this `15b75b40875`.

I will then advise you against using the original file name to save it in the server file system, it is a much better idea to save the original file name in a DB along with the server path it points to.

Then when the user needs to retrieve it's file you will have both the original file name and the file path to download.

User can upload file with very long file names, names which can contain special characters, malicious paths (containing `../..` or similar things).

It is much safer to keep the filename on db and use the server file system as a simple BLOB indexed table.

### UPDATE

If you want to save one file just one time, is better to check for its content, not the name, here a simple example which check the md5 signature of the file, if it does not match an existing upload, it saves the file otherwise it deletes it.

You must keep reference of the name on a DB, but it's safe, and it matches contents instead of names.

```
private void save(byte [] bytes, File baseDir) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {

    File file = File.createTempFile("upload_", ".tmp");
    try(OutputStream stream =  new FileOutputStream(file)){
        MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("md5");
        try(DigestOutputStream digestOutputStream = new DigestOutputStream(stream, digest)){
            digestOutputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
            byte[] signature = digest.digest();
            String newName = md5ToStr(signature);

            File outFile = new File(baseDir,newName);
            if(outFile.exists()){
                // Already present;
                file.delete();
            }else{
                Files.move(file.toPath(), outFile.toPath(), REPLACE_EXISTING, ATOMIC_MOVE);
                // File saved
                // Save path reference and file name in DB
            }

        }
    }
}

private String md5ToStr(byte[] signature) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String txt = new HexBinaryAdapter().marshal(signature);
    return txt;
}
```